# implementing circular linked list with java generics

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I am learning java and i am still a beginner.i have written this code to implement a circular linked list and it keeps printing the numbers when i try to print the list. it looks like some kind of an infinite loop maybe. I even tried to use a debug but it didn't do much for me. I would very much appreciate it if you could review the code and see why this is happening. here is the code below. I would be also for giving me feedback on the code :) 
this is the class for the circular linked list

```
public class CircularLinkedList<E> implements API<E> {
    private Node<E> head;
    private int size = 0;

    public void placeAtBeginning(E element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            head.setNext(head);
        }else {
            Node<E> temp = head;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.setNext(temp);
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void placeAtEnd(E element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }else {
            Node<E> temp = head;
            while (temp.getNext() != head) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            temp.setNext(newNode);
        }

        newNode.setNext(head);
        size++;
    }

    public void deleteFromBeginning() {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while (temp.getNext() != head) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        temp.setNext(head.getNext());
        head = head.getNext();
        size --;
    }

    public void deleteFromEnd() {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while(temp.getNext().getNext() != head) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        temp.setNext(head);
        size--;
    }

    public void print() {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while(temp.getNext()!= head) {
            System.out.print(temp.getValue() + " , ");
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        System.out.print(temp.getValue());
    }
}
```

this is the class for my node

```
public class Node<T> {
    private Node<T> next;
    private T item;

    public Node(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.item;
    }
}
```

this is my main where i tried to test it using int.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        API <Integer> list = new CircularLinkedList<Integer>();

        int a = 10;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 15;
        int d = 8;
        int f = 9;

        list.placeAtBeginning(a);
        list.placeAtEnd(b);
        list.print();
        System.out.println();
        list.placeAtBeginning(c);
        list.placeAtBeginning(d);
        list.print();
    }
}
```

this is my API which I used

```
public interface API <E> {
    public void placeAtBeginning(E element);
    public void placeAtEnd(E element);
    public void deleteFromBeginning();
    public void deleteFromEnd();
    public void print();
}
```

Comment: Infinite loops are perfect situations for stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: i tried but its not working on eclipse. thank you for feedback

Comment: Explain "not working". Is the code failing to hit a breakpoint, or are you unable to find the infinite loop itself?

Comment: it keeps printing the numbers in the list and it does not terminate. maybe some kind of an infinite loop

Comment: That means you have a loop in your linked list somewhere because an insertion / deletion was not performed correctly. Step through the code with a debugger every time you insert / delete a node, and check that the pointer arrangement is exactly as you would expect.

Comment: Check out `placeAtBeginning()`: if the original circular list is not empty then the new head becomes the new element while the `next` of the new element refers to the original circular list. In other words, it doesn't insert the new element in the existing circle. You should search for the last element (the one whose 'next' refers to head) and update 'next' of that element.

Comment: By the way, you got an error in both `delete` methods: Set `head` to `null` after having deleted the last element. Furthermore, both should check the list is not empty before trying to delete an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `placeAtBeginning()` doesn't insert the new element in the circular list but simply lets the `next` of the new element refer to the original circular list.

Try this:

```
public void placeAtBeginning(E element)
{
  Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);
  if(head == null)
  {
    head = newNode;
    head.setNext(head);
  }
  else
  {
    Node<E> last = head;
    while (last.getNext() != head)
      last = last.getNext();
    newNode.setNext(head);
    head = newNode;
    last.setNext(head);
  }
  size++;
}
```

I didn't check the other methods. They might contain a similar error.

Comment: thank you. this worked. i missed the part about the tail pointing to the start :)

Comment: In case you're going to insert and remove elements frequently and especially if the list contains a lot of elements, I suggest you to add a property to your class that keeps track of the last node within the list. This because at every operation you need to search for it.